# RKHunter report: "No hash value found"

Tags: freebsd, perl, hash, rkhunter

I'm getting RKHunter warnings every day when my cron job runs the check.
I'm on FreeBSD 10.2

This is the warning I'm getting:

`Warning: No hash value found for file '/usr/bin/perl' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.`

I already tried `rkhunter --update`and `rkhunter --propupd` but the warning remains.

```
rkhunter --propupd
[ Rootkit Hunter version 1.4.2 ]
File updated: searched for 171 files, found 113, broken links 1
```

`rkhunter --list perl` reveals this:

```
Perl module installation status:
perl command               Installed
File::stat                 Installed
Getopt::Long               Installed
Crypt::RIPEMD160            MISSING
Digest::MD5                Installed
Digest::SHA                Installed
Digest::SHA1               Installed
Digest::SHA256              MISSING
Digest::SHA::PurePerl       MISSING
Digest::Whirlpool           MISSING
LWP                         MISSING
URI                         MISSING
HTTP::Status                MISSING
HTTP::Date                  MISSING
Socket                     Installed
Carp                       Installed
```

I installed Rootkit Hunter through the ports tree and am now on 1.4.2.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that Perl 5.20 doesn't use the symlinks in /usr/bin any more.

(Better read those messages!)

They now were pointing to a nonexistent file:

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel         25  4 Mai  2015 perl -> /usr/local/bin/perl5.18.4
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel         25  4 Mai  2015 perl5 -> /usr/local/bin/perl5.18.4
```

I deleted those and now RKHunter is quiet.

```
rm /usr/bin/perl
rm /usr/bin/perl5
```